# Xcode 10.2 GNU-style inline assembly is disabled

Tags: ios, xcode

Today, after updating Xcode and installing the macOS update, errors appeared that did not exist before.

And my Watch Extension application now contains errors:

GNU-style inline assembly is disabled:[image]
[image]

- Could not build module '_Builtin_instrinsics'
- Could not build module 'simd'
- Could not build module 'SceneKit'
- Could not build module 'WatchKit'

I have not found answers yet why this happened. On devices it works fine. The simulator does not even build.

The applications uses watchOS 2.0 & iOS 9.0.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your WatchKit Extension target (or whatever target it's complaining this for), add `-fgnu-inline-asm` to the `Other C Flags` build options. You'll need to file a radar as well as it looks like a bug.

Comment: thank you very much for this solution! Did anyone open radar? If anyone does, please provide the link to follow it

Comment: @inthy There's no way to follow a radar as Apple does not tell you who the other complainant was. You'll have to still file a bug report with them so they take it seriously. Would be good to mark this answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your custom the `Enable Bitcode` build setting (`ENABLE_BITCODE`) on WatchKit Extension target can solve the problem.

All watchOS and tvOS force to enable Bitcode, your custom build settings will cause error from Xcode 10.2 (ignored before Xcode 10.1). on iOS this is optional, and macOS is not supported.

This is often a mistake that you set this value in xcconfig or Project-Level build settings. The correct way for setting Bitcode on iOS target, is to only change the build setting on Tarfet-Level (or wrriting xcconfig with SDK filter)

Comment: This isn’t a good solution, you want Bitcode enabled on your apps to take advantage of several post delivery optimizations and post processing. Moreover, WatchKit here is just one example - I’ve seen this happen to my frameworks too.